# Method to Compare the Fit of of k-Medoids and GMM to my Dataset

Tags: k-means, matlab, gmm

I'm looking for a method(s) to compare the fit of k-Medoids and a GMM.

Currently, I'm looking at the distance between the max-min means of the GMM clusters and comparing that to the max-min medoid locations of the k-Medoids.

Is this a good method or is there better, more accurate methods?

It's a timeseries dataset.

[image]

For example, 'max' is the center of the blue cluster and 'min' in the center of the red cluster.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I presume 'max' means the maximum distance of an observation from its cluster center? And then 'min' would be by definition 0 for `K-Medoids`?

IF that is the case it would seem to be excluding much of the information that a basic `RMSE` would give you. By `RMSE` here I mean the root of the sum of the squares of the distances between the observations and the "center" of their  assigned cluster.   The `RMSE` (or `MAD` if the situation warrants it) does a pretty good job so to choose a different metric clear evidence should be provided

Comment: I have edited my question so show what I mean. By 'max' I mean the top cluster and by 'min I mean the bottom cluster, I would find the difference between then for a max-min value, then compare the max-min for GMM and k-medoids.